# Radio Button Values, Send ONLY one form parameter

Tags: php, mysql

I want to use radio buttons in my application.When i click Male , i want it to input male into the database, when i click Female, it sends female into the database.

Code looks like this

```
<html>
<head></head>
<title>Radio Test</title>
<body>
<h1>Radio Test</h1>
<form name="testform" id="testform" method="post" action="test.php" />
Name : <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" /></br>
    Male <input type="radio" name="male" id="male" value="Male" />
    Female <input type="radio" name="female" id="female" value="FeMale" /></br></p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

For the HTML Area, Now i want to make it output values, but it doesnt respond. My PHP looks like this but instead of sending one value, it sends both

```
<?php

$host = "127.0.0.1"
$user = "root"
$pass = ""
$db = "people_info"

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db) or die('Cannot Connect :'.mysqli_error());
$fullname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['fullname']);
$male = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['male']);
$female = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['female']);

$sql = "insert into data (fullname,male,female) values ('".$fullname."', '".$male."', '".$female."')";
mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die ('Failed Query :'.mysqli_error($con));
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I was thinking of using switch case, but that made it even worse. It didnt send any values as well..

Comment: In databases, you normally don't have one column per each sex (female, male as in your example) but one column (sex) that then contains the sex value (e.g. male, female), for example as [a set](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you should have one column `Gender` in your table. I'm not sure why are you storing it in two different column.

Change your code to following

```
Male <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="Male" />
Female <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="FeMale" /></br></p>
```

Then,

```
 $gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['gender']);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `name` attribute in a radio input specifies it's radio group. Therefore, when you try to submit the form, it sends both values. Specify the name attribute of both to something like `gender`, and it would work.

```html
<label for="male">Male</label> 
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male" />

<label for="female">Female</label> 
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female" />
```

And in the PHP portion, you just need to request that value once, so do it with:
`$gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['gender']);`